# Cannot run rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shell, rubygems, devops, zsh

`rails -v`

```
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

    $ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.
```

I have oh-my-zsh installed.

```
which rails
/usr/bin/rails
```

How I export PATH in `~/.zshrc`:

`export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH`

When I try to install rails it looks like it's not installing anything (note '0' seconds):

```
sudo gem install rails
Successfully installed rails-6.0.3.3
Parsing documentation for rails-6.0.3.3
Done installing documentation for rails after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

Any idea why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: The post install is pretty bad advice. You don't want to use `sudo gem install rails`. Instead use ruby version manager like rbenv or rvm to install ruby which will install gems to a location that does not require sudo and which have shell hooks to place the correct ruby version and gems on your path.

Answer (score 0):

Seem you have problem with rails -v

If you can, use google translate and try to refer this link https://qiita.com/aki319809/items/9de7f14285cd0c69e2d2